# Unity 3D, How can I detect if mouse is over a 2D Sprite even if the Sprite is not visible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, mouse

I work with the Unity3D game engine and I stumbled across this problem.
When I try to check if the mouse is over a sprite, I can do so by using this callback.

```
private void OnMouseOver()
{
    // Do Something
}
```

But if the mouse is not directly over the sprite, this method won't work.
Are there any alternatives?
[image]

The Orange sprite is the sprite I want to detect, but the blue circle makes it to not detect the mouse (This doesn't look really good, I am not an artist, but I should make things clear I hope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know what object(s) are underneath your mouse click, use this:

- [Physics2D.GetRayIntersectionAll(...)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.GetRayIntersectionAll.html)

Example - put it in your update:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    var hits = Physics2D.GetRayIntersectionAll(ray, 1500f);

    foreach (var hit in hits)
    {
        print($"Mouse is over {hit.collider.name}");
    }
}
```

For performance reasons, you may want to use:

- [Physics2D.GetRayIntersectionNonAlloc(...)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.GetRayIntersectionNonAlloc.html)

Comment: Awesome :) It possible, would be great if you could mark this as an answer.